# Using "Like" receiving Error no title given, though title info is being passed

Tags: facebook, web, facebook-like

When "Like" button is clicked an error appears indicating there is not title, though title field is being passed. (Using VB Script to generate title based on information being displayed on page)

additional problems - Does not consistently update Like information on Facebook Wall
- Need help passing unique image into each like field based on what information is being displayed on page.

Example page - http://www.storymall.com/ReadStory.asp?StoryID=42

```
<!--   FACEBook Properties     -->


    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
            <Head>
                <meta property="og:title" content="<%= StoryName %>"/>
                <meta property="og:description" content="<%= StoryDescription %> "/>
                <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
                <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.storymall.com/members/<%= AuthorID %>/<%= image1 %>"/>
                <meta property="og:site_name" content="StoryMall"/>
                <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.storymall.com/ReadStory.asp?StoryID=<%= StoryID %>" />
                <meta property="fb:app_id" content="100002543479604"/>
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
                <meta property="fb:app_id" content="<%= StoryiD %>"/>   
        </Head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Linter says you have errors with the fb:app_id that need to be fixed

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.storymall.com%2FReadStory.asp%3FStoryID%3D42

It's this meta tag

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="<%= StoryiD %>"/>
```

Comment: notice you already have <meta property="fb:app_id" content="100002543479604"/> in the meta's

Comment: I see that we copied the code during one of our test cases. the line you are referring to was really                  <meta property="fb:admins="xxxxxxxx" />  In the real code we only have the fb:app_id described once.  The problem is that no matter what we define fb comes back with the error condition that states we have not supplied a "title" content.

Comment: From the URL linter tool, that URL still shows as being bad.  You will absolutely need to fix what it says you need to fix. Currently, 42 is not a valid app_id.